# Logging requests and responses in Spring

Tags: spring, logging, request, response

I'm trying to implement logging system in a Spring boot application. There are requests coming into the system which have one or more responses. 
Requests and responses must be logged into the database in a separate thread, not in the worker thread.
This is my idea.

tables in mysql - "request" with required columns, and "response" with request_id as foreign key 
relation between resquest and response - one to many. 
A separate thread in `LogService` is started in `@PostContruct` to save the data in the DB.
I'm sure there are better solutions to this problem. Please guide with some suggestions.

```
@Service
public class LogServiceImpl implements LogService {
    private final BlockingQueue<Object> logQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private volatile boolean done;

    // repositories
    @Autowired
    private RequestRepository requestRepository;

    @Autowired 
    private ResponseRepository responseRepository;

    @Async
    @Override
    public void log(Object obj) {
        try {
            logQueue.put(obj);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @PostContruct
    private saveToDb(){
        new Thread(() -> {
            while(!done){
                String object = logQueue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                if(object != null){
                    if(object instanceof Request){
                        requestRepository.save((Request)object);
                    }
                    if(object instanceof Response){
                        responseRepository.save((Response)object);  
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        done = true;
    }
}

class Request{
    .....
}

class Response{
    ......
}

@Service
public class SomeService1 {
    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    public void someMeth1(Request request) {
        ....
        logService.log(request);
    }
}

@Service
public class SomeService2 {
    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    public void someMeth2(Response response) {
        ....
        logService.log(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

Comment: @nfechner  The request and response classes have nothing common with mvc, the requests are coming in through the socket. Can I use HandlerInterceptor in this case?

Comment: Of course not. Interceptors work only on spring controllers. You really should ask yourself if working on sockets is absolutely necessary. It usually only complicates things and gives no benefit (In my experience using them is usually a case of premature optimization).